# Variable isn't changing as it goes through the loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a first time programmer trying to learn Excel VBA, running into some trouble.

Program is running to calculate the appropriate size of a damper for available area.  Everything is calculating correctly except for the variable DampW as it goes through the loop.  As it calculates the different dampers sizes the DampW variable isn't changing when the DampH variable is changed.  The DampH is adjusted in the FOR Loop.

I also noticed that when running against the current conditions the program should exit, as the condition of DampCheck is equal to "OK".  However, the program enters the loop.

Please let me know if there is any confusion on what I'm asking.  Want to make sure I posted this correctly.

```
Public Sub DamperCalcs1()

DampType = Range("DampType").Value

'Activates the damper spreadsheet
Sheets(DampType).Activate

'Calculates the maximum height allowed from the spreadsheet with damper sizes
'Counts the number of 0 in column "O" and returns the maximum height 
MaxH1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$7:$C$" & 2 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("$O:$O"), 0)))

'Pulls out the minimum height of the specified damper for the air handling unit from the damper spreadsheet
MinH = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ActiveSheet.Range("$C$7:$C$7000"))

'Calculates the maximum Height allowed for damper sizing calculations
If DampType = "None" Then
    MaxH2 = Sheets("inputs Performance").Range("$C$12")

    ElseIf Sheets("Inputs Performance").Range("$C$12") > MaxH1 Then
        MaxH2 = MaxH1

    Else
        MaxH2 = Sheets("Inputs Performance").Range("$C$12")

End If

'Calculates a true damper height with standard blade configuration

'Setting max height value as an integer with a calculation
MaxH3 = [(MaxH2-3.75)/5.75]


'Calculates the Maximum damper height for calculations
If (MaxH3 * 5.75) < MinH Then
    MaxH4 = MinH

    Else
        MaxH4 = (MaxH3 * 5.75) + 3.75
End If

'Calculates the height addition for a louver
If Left(DampType, 3) = "ELF" Then
    DampH = 3 + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MaxH4, 9.5)

    Else
        DampH = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MaxH4, 9.5)

End If

'Outputs the maximum and minimum values required
Sheet33.Range("B2").Value = MaxH1
Sheet33.Range("B3").Value = MinH
Sheet33.Range("B5").Value = MaxH2

'Outputs the actual damper height
Sheet33.Range("B7").Value = DampH

End Sub
```

Start of Second Sub Program

```
Public Sub DamperCalcs2()

CFM = Range("CFM").Value
MaxFPM = Range("MaxFPM").Value

  'Assigns a given value for variables required to calculate the EAML damper
EAMLA = 3.23750323750089E-07
EAMLB = -9.29262202444403E-03
EAMLC = 3.82761707988981E-03
EAMLD = -3.44782545737092E-02
EAMLE = 5.00341409432224E-07
EAMLF = 8.40487603305808E-03

If Left(DampType, 3) = "ELF" Then
     DampW = [RoundUp((((CFM / MaxFPM - Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DampH, Sheets("Free Area").Range("$B$113:$E$132"), 2, False)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DampH, Sheets("Free Area").Range("$B$113:$E$132"), 4, False)) + 12), 0)]

     ElseIf DampType = "EAML" Then
        DampW = [RoundUp((-(EAMLD + EAMLC * DampH) + SQRT((EAMLD + EAMLC * DampH) ^ 2 - (4 * (EAMLE * (-(CFM / MaxFPM) + EAMLF + EAMLA * DampH * DampH + EAMLB * DampH))))) / (2 * EAMLE), 0)]

    Else
        DampW = [RoundUp((144 * (CFM / MaxFPM) / DampH), 0)]
End If

DampType = Range("DampType").Value

'Selects the damper spreadsheet
Sheets(DampType).Select

DampRange = ("$C$3:$C$" & 1 + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("$O:$O"), 0))

'number of heights in total range less than input height (use as origin for adjusted range on widths)
DampCount1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range(DampRange), "<" & DampH) + 3

'number of heights in total range equal input height (use as origin for adjusted range on widths)
DampCount2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range(DampRange), "=" & DampH)

'Sheets("Calc Performance 2").Activate
DampType = Range("DampType").Value

'Selects the damper spreadsheet
Sheets(DampType).Activate

'Creates a new range for damper heights
AdjDampRange = ("D" & DampCount1 & ":D" & (DampCount1 + DampCount2 - 1))

'number of widths in adjusted range less than clculated width
DampWCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range(AdjDampRange), "<" & DampW)

'Calculates the line number to pull the actual damper width from
ActualDampWLine = DampCount1 + DampWCount

'Pulls the actual damper width from the spreadsheet
ActualDampW = Range("D" & ActualDampWLine).Value

DampLoc = Range("DampLoc").Value

'Calculates the hood depth for the max height of damper

If Left(DampType, 3) = "ELF" Or DampType = "EAML" Or DampLoc = "TOP" Or DampLoc = "BOTTOM" Then
     Hood1 = 0

    ElseIf Left(DampType, 3) = "AMS" And DampLoc = "Front" Then
        Hood1 = [RoundUp((DampH*DampW*1200)/((DampW+4)*1000)+8,0)]

   ElseIf Left(DampType, 3) = "AMS" And DampLoc = "Side" Then
        Hood1 = [RoundUp((DampH*DampW*1200)/((DampW+4)*1000)+16,0)]

   ElseIf Left(DampType, 2) = "CD" And DampLoc = "Front" Then
       Hood1 = [RoundUp((DampH*DampW*1200)/((DampW+4)*1000),0)]

   ElseIf Left(DampType, 2) = "CD" And DampLoc = "Side" Then
       Hood1 = [RoundUp((DampH*DampW*1200)/((DampW+4)*1000)+8,0)]

End If

'Determines if Damper or Louver is acceptable
If Sheets(DampType).Cells(3, ActualDampWLine) > DampH Or DampH > MaxH Or ActualDampW > MaxW Then  'Removed the following from check to tryout program Or Hood1 > 60
    DampCheck = "X"
    Else
        DampCheck = "OK"
End If

'Outputs the actual damper height
Sheet33.Range("B9").Value = DampW

'Outputs the actual damper height
Sheet33.Range("B11").Value = DampRange
Sheet33.Range("B12").Value = DampCount1
Sheet33.Range("B13").Value = DampCount2
Sheet33.Range("B15").Value = AdjDampRange
Sheet33.Range("B16").Value = DampWCount
Sheet33.Range("B18").Value = ActualDampWLine
Sheet33.Range("B19").Value = ActualDampW
Sheet33.Range("B20").Value = Hood1
Sheet33.Range("B22").Value = DampCheck

Sheets("Calc Performance 2").Select
End Sub
```

Program used to call the two sub programs with loop included.

```
Public Sub TrialCalc3()

Call DamperCalcs1
Call DamperCalcs2

If DampCheck = "OK" Then
Sheet33.Range("B24").Value = "Macro Finished on first run"

    Else
        For LoopCount = 1 To 6
            If DampCheck = "OK" Then
                Sheet33.Range("B24").Value = "Macro Finished between Loop runs"
                Exit Sub

                Else
                    DampH = DampH - 5.75
                    Call DamperCalcs2

            End If
        Next
End If

'Outputs the actual damper height
Sheet33.Range("C7").Value = DampH
Sheet33.Range("C9").Value = DampW

'Outputs the actual damper height
Sheet33.Range("C11").Value = DampRange
Sheet33.Range("C12").Value = DampCount1
Sheet33.Range("C13").Value = DampCount2
Sheet33.Range("C15").Value = AdjDampRange
Sheet33.Range("C16").Value = DampWCount
Sheet33.Range("C18").Value = ActualDampWLine
Sheet33.Range("C19").Value = ActualDampW
Sheet33.Range("C20").Value = Hood1
Sheet33.Range("C22").Value = DampCheck

End Sub
```

Global Variables as assigned at the top of the module

```
Option Explicit
Public Damptype As String, DampTab As Variant, MaxH1 As Double, MaxH2 As Double, MinH As Double, MaxH3 As Integer, MaxH4 As Double, DampH As Double, MaxH As Double, MaxW As Double
Public CFM As Double, MaxFPM As Double, DampW As Double, EAMLA As Double, EAMLB As Double, EAMLC As Double, EAMLD As Double, EAMLE As Double, EAMLF As Double
Public DampRange As Variant, DampCount1 As Double, DampCount2 As Double
Public AdjDampRange As Variant, DampWCount As Double, ActualDampW As Double, ActualDampWLine As Double, DampCheck As String
Public DampLoc As String, Hood1 As Integer, LoopCount As Integer
```

Added the following lines of code into the DampW calculation to see what I was getting.

```
If Left(Damptype, 3) = "ELF" Then
    DampW = [RoundUp((((CFM / MaxFPM - Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DampH, Sheets("Free Area").Range("$B$113:$E$132"), 2, False)) / Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DampH, Sheets("Free Area").Range("$B$113:$E$132"), 4, False)) + 12), 0)]

    ElseIf Damptype = "EAML" Then
        DampW = [RoundUp(144 * (CFM / MaxFPM) / DampH, 0)]
    Else
        DampW = [RoundUp(144 * (CFM / MaxFPM) / DampH, 0)]
        MsgBox "MaxFPM is " & MaxFPM & " and Damper Height is " & DampH & " and New Damper Width " & DampW

End If
```

What I'm getting as output is listed below:

MaxFPM is equal to 1800 (Standard for all DampW calculations)
DampH is equal to 61.25 (Which is the correct height when adjusted)
DampW is equal to 36 (Which is the original number, should be 40 after calculation)

The damper width at this point should've adjusted to 33, instead it's remaining at the original 36.  Don't understand what I've done wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the code enter into the IFs at the start of the second sub? Your code is long but DampType = Range("DampType").Value looks like it should be before the IFs.

Comment: Tried moving the DampType = Range("DampType").Value above the first If statement.  That actually made the selection worse.

Comment: See Gary's student's answer. Your subs cannot see the variables declared in other subs unless they are passed to one another (unless they are public variables declared at the start of your code). That's why I wanted you to give the variable a value before using it - but it needs to be declared first. if it is supposed to be the same, pass it as an argument.

Comment: I've got the global Variables assigned at the top of the module

Comment: It appears for some reason that the New DampH value isn't being passed back into the sub program.  As the DampW and Hood1 values aren't changing When the DampH value is updated in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks reasonable, but the **Subs** are not communicating properly.  For example, **Sub** *TrialCalcs3* examines the variable *DampCheck*.  But it cannot "see" the variable, because it is not **Global** in scope.

For routines to be able to "share" variables, they must either be **Global** in scope (that is Public) or passed as parameters.

Comment: Appologies, I didn't include the global parameter section in my posting.  I've included all the variables in an Option Explicit section listing them as Public.